# Jump to next tab in asp.net using java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, aspbutton

i am using `jquery` tabs. know i want to jump to the next tab `onclick` of button. here is my code

```
 <div id="tabs">
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="#tabs-1">Basic Information</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#tabs-2">Authors</a></li>
             </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
     <asp:Button ID="btnSaveAuthors" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="button medium green" />
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
        </div>
 </div>
```

but when i use this javascript function.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=btnSaveAuthors.ClientId%>").click(function (event) 
            {
                $('#tabs').tabs('select', 1);
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

it gives me following error

```
Error   5   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' does not contain a definition for 'ClientId' and no extension method 'ClientId' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

plesase help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "d" in "ClientId" should be capital: "ClientID"

Comment: yes it solve the error but it does'nt go to next tabe. it just refresh the page

Comment: If you don't want the button to perform a postback, then you can try calling event.preventDefault() inside the click function. This should prevent the button from doing a postback, which is what it usually does. If you still want to do the postback then you will probably want to cause the tabs to change on the server-side, rather than the client-side.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you are using C# which is case sensitive, and the correct name should be **'ClientID'**:
[Control.ClientID Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx)

Comment: yes it solve the error but it does'nt go to next tabe. it just refresh the page